# NoReverseMatch at /restaurant/meal/9/edit/ at Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I created a `restaurant_delete_meal` function to delete meal object . 
When I run the link `restaurant/meal/id/delete` the function works and deletes the object. But when I try to add a button in the edit-meal page with the url of delete meal function and i try to open the edit-meal page get this error

```
NoReverseMatch at /restaurant/meal/9/edit/
Reverse for 'restaurant-delete-meal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['restaurant/meal/(?P<meal_id>\\d+)/delete/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/meal/9/edit/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'restaurant-delete-meal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['restaurant/meal/(?P<meal_id>\\d+)/delete/$']
Exception Location:  
/Users/mickael/Desktop/myvirtualenv/foodtasker/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:   
/Users/mickael/Desktop/myvirtualenv/foodtasker/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/mickael/Desktop/foodtasker',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib- 
dynload',
'/Users/mickael/Desktop/myvirtualenv/foodtasker/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages']
Server time:    Wed, 16 May 2018 11:16:53 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template 
/Users/mickael/Desktop/foodtasker/foodtaskerapp/templates/base.html, 
error at line 25

Reverse for 'restaurant-delete-meal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['restaurant/meal/(?P<meal_id>\\d+)/delete/$']
```

I  imported all the views. The edit meal page where I try to set the delete button:

```
 [views.py][1]
 [urls.py][2]
 [edit-meal.html][3]
```

Views.py

```
    def restaurant_delete_meal(request, meal_id):
        instance = get_object_or_404(Meal, id=meal_id)
        instance.delete()
        messages.success(request, "DELETED")
        return redirect(restaurant_meal)
```

edit_meal.html when i try to set the button

```
       {% extends 'restaurant/base.html' %}
       {% load bootstrap3 %}

       {% block page %}



<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-blue">
            <h4 class="panel-title text-center text-white">
                Edit Meal
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form form %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink">Update</button>

            </form>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-pink" id="right-panel-link" href="{% url 'restaurant-delete-meal' meal.id %}">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

     {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^restaurant/meal/(?P<meal_id>\d+)/delete/$', 
 views.restaurant_delete_meal, name = 'restaurant-delete-meal'),
```

Comment: Can you please add all code relevant to your question? People are usually not so keen on opening images. :)

Comment: Your `restaurant-delete-meal` view expects a `meal_id` argument but you are trying to use `{% url %}` without a `meal_id`.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: i added the code

Comment: ??? Plz i am searching for a solution